# cannot open pdf url in android using inAppBrowser cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, pdf

i have a pdf url and i want to open it with my Android using inAppBrowser plugin. I have added the plugin into my cordova app. and here is my script

```
<script>
   var doc = new jsPDF();
   doc.text('hello');
   var uri = doc.output('datauristring'); //pdf url
</script>

<button onclick="window.open(uri, '_system')">test</button>
```

i also tried my button like this but it doesn't open. and there is no response at all. 
`window.open('data:application/pdf;base64,blabla...', '_system')`

but in my laptop, it will display correctly. any answer will be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: Did you install cordova whitelist plugin?

Comment: i have installed it too.

Comment: @MuhammadRauuf, have you added cordova.js file in your html? also have you define 'deviceready' event listener in your script?

Comment: @Gandhi i have added them. but, if i change the url to `'http://stackoverflow.com'` , window.open will open that link correctly.

Comment: Update your config.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your config.xml file add the following line.

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

It should work

Location of config.xml: `\Your Project Folder\platforms\android\res\xml`

Comment: still same. if link is `'http://google.com'`, it's worked, but if i change link to my pdf url, it doesn't open. here is my full pdf link

`data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMKMyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9QYWdlCi9QYXJlbnQgMSAwIFIKL1Jlc291cmNlcyAyIDAgUgovTWVkaWFCb3ggWzAgMCA1OTUuMjggODQxLjg5XQovQ29udGVudHMgNCAwIFIKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjQgMCBvYmoKPDwvTGVuZ3RoIDYwPj4Kc3RyZWFtCjAuNTcgdwowIEcKQlQKL0YxIDE2IF....` 

the link is too long

Comment: Looks like your links is not  valid. please give a correct link

Comment: that's my pdf link, it works when i open in my laptop with chrome.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
url = "https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+YOUR_PDF_LINK;
var documentLink = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', 'location=no,hardwareback=yes');

documentLink.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {

});

documentLink.addEventListener('exit', function(event) {
    documentLink.removeEventListener("loadstart", function(e){});
});
```

You need to install InAppBrowser plugin

Comment: Yes, I'm still using this in my apps.

Comment: Could you give an example of `YOUR_PDF_LINK`? Can we pass a `Base64` encoded PDF representation here or is the path to a downloaded file required? Also, what is the purpose of the `addEventListener` functions?